# I want to modify postgresql.conf listening address

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

How to Modify postgresql.conf listening address. whenever i open file and edit then could not save me.
any other method i can do this to open and modify postgresql.conf file?

Comment: It's a text file. Use a text editor and change it.

Comment: Do you edit it as admin? Which OS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i try to edit on editor. show error don't have permission to necessary save file.

Comment: @jeprubio yes but permission error.

Comment: Then you are not editing it as admin. In which Operating System is running?

Comment: @jeprubio any solution for this ?

Comment: ubuntu operating system

Comment: `sudo su - postgres`  then edit the file

Comment: use `sudo` to edit it. Ex: `sudo vi postgresql.conf` (with the vi editor in this case). Press `i` to start editing and type `:wq` to write and quit.

Comment: Or use another solution from here https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+edit+as+root

Comment: @jeprubio i want to remove something there is no option to remove word.

Comment: you must be in the `insert mode` to edit the text (just press `i`) first, vi is a little tricky to manage but it's really good to know at least the basics as you can find it in almost all unix systems. When you have all the content just press `esc` key and `:wq` to write and quit (or  `:q!` to discard the changes and start again if you are not sure it's OK)

Answer (score 2):

Your user dont have priveledge to edit. You can use sudo

```
sudo vim postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

To modify `postgresql.conf` file, first find the location of the postgresql.conf file, there can be multiple file if you have installed multiple version of postgresql on your computer. To do this type:

```
locate postgresql.conf
```

This will provide the path of all `postgresql.conf` file available on your computer.
Now based on your choice select one and open it with a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<version>/main/postgresql.conf
```

It is important to open it as a `root` user.